# Does Strong Stochastic ordering exist?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

For two probability measure $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we call $\mu$ is *stochastically smaller* than $\nu$ (i.e., $\mu\leq\nu$) , if $\int f d\mu\leq\int f d\nu$ for any nonnegative bounded increasing measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

There is a fact that $\mu\leq\nu$ is equivalent to $F_{\mu}(x)\geq F_{\nu}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $F_{\mu}(x)$ and $F_{\nu}(x)$ are the cumulative distribution functions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

Another fact is that, $\mu\leq\nu$ is equivalent to $\int f d\mu\leq\int f d\nu$ for any nonnegative bounded increasing measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with Lipschitz constant less or equal to 1.

I'm curious about whether there is a *strong order* in this ordered space. That is to say, can we find some topology in probability space such that, there exists two probability measure $\mu$ and $\nu$, and their open neighborhood $\mu\in U$, $\nu\in V$ in this topology such that, $\tilde{\mu}\leq \tilde{\nu}$, for any $\tilde{\mu}\in U$ and $\tilde{\nu}\in V$.

I guess we cannot find such open sets in weak convergence topology, or wasserstein metric $W_p$ (I cannot prove it strictly now). And I cannot imagine such topology and open sets exist, since we need to gurantee the distribution sufficiently close to the inital probability measure in its neighborhood.

The same question also exists for other partial order in the probability space.

Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Total variation perhaps. Its topology is rather special

Comment: Like the weak topology or the W_p distance topology, I can hardly say there is  strong order in total variation distance topology, nor can I strictly prove it. The intuition tells me that for any $\mu\leq\nu$, perturbate the distribution function of $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that it changes little near $-\infty$ will cause contradiction.

Comment: What about L infinity difference between CDFs?

Comment: Though that would not help as stochastic dominance can still lead to CDFs being as close as you want over the tails

Comment: Yes, I think common metric cannot have this strong order property.

Comment: You can always take discrete metric

Comment: Yes, discrete metric or some metric close to discrete metric seem to be useful here.

Comment: There is an answer here. The Infinite Wasserstein Distance. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457710/does-strong-stochastic-ordering-exist

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the notion of the strong order, but you can always take the discrete topology to make this order (or any other one) into a strong order the way you've defined it. Unless you impose some restrictions on the size of this topology (e.g. second countable), the answer remain trivial.